# getting error as -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

```
I have to fetch the reqid and appprimaycontact from ssoSummaryVOMap part in the json the structure of json is  below .
```

While fetching the json                   I am getting error as

```
 2016-05-16 15:18:48.360 Sip[30390:317309] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fc2e2e060
    2016-05-16 15:18:48.377 Sip[30390:317309] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fc2e2e060'
```

My json Data is

```
 json{
        appExIntgRequestId = 0;
        appQuestionnaireStatus = "E1 Pending";
        description = "Questionnaire retrieved successfully";
        isAdminRole = 0;
        isSuperAdminRole = 0;
        logoutUrl = "https://ssointrad.dev.ipc.us.aexp.com/SSOI/request?request_type=un_logoff&SSOURL=";
        quesSubmitType = 0;
        requestDeleted = 0;
        returnCode = 0;
        saveBeforeLogoff = 0;
        ssoQuestionnaireGeneralInfoVO =     {
            aimId = 200109736;
            appPrimaryContactCountryCode = 1;
            appPrimaryContactEmail = "ssoipAppUser@aexp.com";
            appPrimaryContactName = "ssoipApp User";
            appPrimaryContactPhone = 2232323123;
            appPrimaryContactPhone1 = 223;
            appPrimaryContactPhone2 = 232;
            appPrimaryContactPhone3 = 3123;
            appSecondaryContactCountryCode = "<null>";
            appSecondaryContactEcn = "<null>";
            appSecondaryContactEmail = "ssoipnonadmin@aexp.com";
            appSecondaryContactName = "ssoip NonAdmin";
            appSecondaryContactPhone = "<null>";
            appSecondaryContactPhone1 = "<null>";
            appSecondaryContactPhone2 = "<null>";
            appSecondaryContactPhone3 = "<null>";
            applicationName = "App Dir ITGC";
            engagementNo = 1264281;
            projMasterDC = PTY123567Y;
            requestId = 41458;
            ssoProjManagerEmail = "ssoip.Admin5@aexp.com";
            ssoProjManagerName = "ssoip Admin5";
            ssoTechLeadEmail = "ssoip.Admin4@aexp.com";
            ssoTechLeadName = "ssoip Admin4";
        };
        ssoQuestionnaireSpecificDetailsVO =     {
            appAjaxCalls = 0;
            appAliasName = "SIP_R6PerfTesting_Internet_51206";
            appAuthnTypeId = "-1";
            appBranding = 0;
            appChangeDetails = "";
            appChangeReasonId = "-1";
            appCoarseAuthorization = "-1";
            appCustomPages = 0;
            appDependencyAimIdList =         {
            };
            appDependencyAll = "<null>";
            appDependencyid = 0;
            appDomainId = 2;
            appE1ImplDate = "05/23/2016";
            appE2ImplDate = "07/11/2016";
            appE3ImplDate = "08/09/2016";
            appExclusiveRegistration = 0;
            appExistingRegAimIdAll = "<null>";
            appExistingRegServiceIdAll = "<null>";
            appExistingRegistration = 0;
            appHostingenvironmentId = 1;
            appInternalHostingEnvId = 1;
            appLocaleAll = "en_US|";
            appLocaleList =         (
                "en_US"
            );
            appProviderType = "-1";
            appRATypeId = 4;
            appReleaseEnvironmentE1 = 2;
            appReleaseEnvironmentE2 = 3;
            appReleaseEnvironmentE3 = 4;
            appSSOIntegrated = 0;
            appSamlCompatible = "-1";
            appSamlVersion = 0;
            appServersProvisioned = 0;
            appServiceIdAimIdList1 = "<null>";
            appServiceIdAimIdList2 = "<null>";
            appSsoPassParameters = 1;
            appUserDomainId = 2;
            appUserOrigination = 1;
            appUserTypeAll = "<null>";
            appUserTypeList =         (
            );
            appWebServerBitCompilation = "-1";
            appWebServerOS = Others;
            appWebServerOSBitCompilation = "-1";
            appWebServerType = "<null>";
            appaimidserviceid =         {
            };
        };
        ssoSummaryVOMap =     {
            41178 =         {
                aimId = 0;
                aliasName = "Alias_test_783_new_Testing";
                appName = "<null>";
                **appPrimaryContact = "<null>";**
                domainName = IntErnet;
                engagementNo = "<null>";
                hostingEnv = "Internally Hosted(Amex)";
                reqDate = "<null>";
                **reqId = 41178;**
                ssoProjManager = "<null>";
                ssoTechLead = "<null>";
                status = "<null>";
            };
            41227 =         {
                aimId = 0;
                aliasName = "Alias_new_testing_243721";
                appName = "<null>";
                **appPrimaryContact = "<null>";**
                domainName = IntrAnet;
                engagementNo = "<null>";
                hostingEnv = "Internally Hosted(Amex)";
                reqDate = "<null>";
                **reqId = 41227;**
                ssoProjManager = "<null>";
                ssoTechLead = "<null>";
                status = "<null>";
            };
            41259 =         {
                aimId = 0;
                aliasName = "Alias_test_848_testing";
                appName = "<null>";
                **appPrimaryContact = "<null>";**
                domainName = IntrAnet;
                engagementNo = "<null>";
                hostingEnv = "Internally Hosted(Amex)";
                reqDate = "<null>";
                **reqId = 41259;**
                ssoProjManager = "<null>";
                ssoTechLead = "<null>";
                status = "<null>";
            };
            41302 =         {
                aimId = 0;
                aliasName = "Alias_new_testing_4563";
                appName = "<null>";
                appPrimaryContact = "<null>";
                domainName = IntrAnet;
                engagementNo = "<null>";
                hostingEnv = "Internally Hosted(Amex)";
                reqDate = "<null>";
                reqId = 41302;
                ssoProjManager = "<null>";
                ssoTechLead = "<null>";
                status = "<null>";
            };
        };
        status = "PROC_EXEC_SUCCESS";
    }


    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Did Finish");
        // Do something with responseData



        NSString *strData=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


        NSData *jsonData = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@" json%@", json);
        NSArray* info = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"];
           NSLog(@" ssoSummaryVOMap%@", info);

        for(int i=0; i<info.count; i++){
            NSMutableDictionary * requestId= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            requestId = [info objectAtIndex:i];


        }

        NSLog(@" the name is %@ ", _appPrimaryContact);
        NSLog(@" the reqid is %@", _reqId);
        NSLog(@" the status is %@", _status);




     i tried everything to get to the solution but no luck . 
     Please help .
```

Comment: NSArray* info = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"]; NSLog(@" ssoSummaryVOMap%@", info);

Can you send the details of NSLog for the above

Comment: The contents of `ssoSummaryVOMap` are dictionaries but in your code you are treating them as arrays. Treat them as dictionary and your code should work,

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have try with NSdictionary also but still getting the sam response .

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
NSDictionjary *yourJSON = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"];
id object = [yourJSON objectForKey:@"41178"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . But I have iterate the json to get request id ( as 41178) as it may differ each time . from that id  i have to select primary contact status field.

Comment: @Rv1190, You can iterate NSDictionary with block:
 [defaultSettings enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {        
    }];

Your "keys" will be "41227", "41302" etc. and your values are the content for each key.

Answer (score 1):

easily you can get values use code ..

```
// ssoSummaryVOMap key denotes a parent dictionary 
NSDictionjary *yourJSON = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"];
// same 41178 key also denotes a dictionary which is sub dict of previous  
NSDictionjary *subDict = [yourJSON objectForKey:@"41178"];
// you can easily get the particular value now
NSString *value = [subDict objectForKey:@"aliasName"];
NSLog(@"response = %@",value);
```

happy coding ..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . But I just cannot hard code 41178 value as it is different each time . I have to iterate through the array to get the each index value and then for that index i have to fetch key value pair .

Comment: there is nothing to hard code here if **you can iterate your parent dict keys instead of putting 41178 each time** .. here users can only give their own ideas you can convert it useful by putting your own efforts ..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"Key1" : @"Value1"}, @{@"Key2" : @"Value2"}, @{@"Key3" : @"Value3"}];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict.allKeys);
    for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
        NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, dict[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite these lines

```
NSArray* info = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"];
NSLog(@" ssoSummaryVOMap%@", info);

for(int i=0; i<info.count; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary * requestId= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    requestId = [info objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

into something like this...

```
NSDictionary* info = [json objectForKey:@"ssoSummaryVOMap"];
NSLog(@" ssoSummaryVOMap%@", info);

for(int i=0; i<info.count; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary * requestId = [((NSDictionary *)(info.allValues[i])) mutableCopy];
}
```

Note that you should really add some sense-checking code.